# How to pass in AWS environmental variables to Nextflow for use in Docker container

Tags: docker, nextflow

I would like to run a Nextflow pipeline through a Docker container. As part of the pipeline I would like to push and pull from AWS. To accomplish this end, I need to pass in AWS credentials to the container, but I do not want to write them into the image.

Nextflow has an option to pass in environmental variables as part of the Docker scope via the envWhitelist option, however I have not been able to find an example for correct syntax when doing this.

I have tried the following syntax and get an access denied error, suggesting that I am not passing in the variables properly.

```
docker {
 enabled = true
 envWhitelist = "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
}
```

I explicitly passed these variables into my environment and I can see them using printenv.

Does this syntax seem correct? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I added an answer, but I'm not sure if I have understood your question. Are you using AWS Batch? Are you running Nextflow with something like: `nextflow run <your script> -with-docker [docker image]`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just keep your [AWS security credentials](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/aws.html#aws-security-credentials) in a file called `~/.aws/credentials`:

> If `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are not defined in the
> environment, Nextflow will attempt to retrieve credentials from your
> `~/.aws/credentials` or `~/.aws/config` files.

Alternatively, you can declare your AWS credentials in your nextflow.config (or in a separate config profile) using the [`aws` scope](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-aws):

```
aws {
    accessKey = '<YOUR S3 ACCESS KEY>'
    secretKey = '<YOUR S3 SECRET KEY>'
    region = '<REGION IDENTIFIER>'
}
```

You could also use an [IAM Instance Role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/granting-permission-to-launch-ec2-instances-with-iam-roles-passrole-permission/) to provide your credentials.